# Remove duplicates from List using Guava

Tags: java, list, generics, arraylist, guava

How can we remove duplicates from List with the help of **Guava api**?

Currently I am following this:

```
private List<T> removeDuplicate(List<T> list){
return new ArrayList<T>(new LinkedHashSet<T>(list));
}
```

Comment: why you like to go for guava, if basic set does this?

Comment: and in such a concise fashion, too

Comment: @PriyankDoshi why not just `HashSet`?

Comment: @PriyankDoshi , use java HashSet collection class

Comment: @veer : I needed to preserve Order. So used LinkedHashSet

Comment: @MohammodHossain No, `LinkedHashSet` is the right choice because it will preserve element order.

Comment: I like your current solution!

Comment: @JigarJoshi : I ve just started learning guava and it feels so awesome that now everything I want to do , do with guava..!!. Big fan. :)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Probably the most efficient way is `ImmutableSet.copyOf(list).asList()`, which eliminates duplicates and preserves iteration order.

(But your implementation with `LinkedHashSet` would be nearly as efficient, and wouldn't throw up on nulls, in the unlikely event you actually wanted nulls in your collection.)

Comment: _If_ you don't have null elements ;)

Comment: True, but 95% of collections don't.

Answer (score 12):

I love [Louis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12248480/342852) for the simplicity of it (and because it's the only answer that doesn't require 2 full iterations), but unfortunately in the real world, you often encounter situations where `null` does occur. Here's a slightly longer null-safe version:

```
ImmutableSet.copyOf(
    Iterables.filter(
        list, Predicates.not(Predicates.isNull()))).asList();
```

Or, with static imports:

```
copyOf(filter(list, not(isNull()))).asList();
```

Of course you need to be aware of the fact that all `null` Values will be lost from the List.

Comment: There's a `Predicates.notNull()` predicate already available. So the final result would be `copyOf(filter(list, notNull())).asList();`.

Comment: @Jonas true. but at the time I wrote this the method didn't exist

Answer (score 7):

with generic predicate

```
class DuplicateRemover<T> implements Predicate<T> {

    private final Set<T> set = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public boolean apply(T input) {

        boolean flag = set.contains(input);

        if (!flag) {
            set.add(input);
        }

        return !flag;
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that set.add returns true only if the element was actually added, so the call to set.contains is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna use Guava at any price you can do

```
return new ArrayList<T>(HashMultiSet<T>.create(list).elementSet())
```

Answer (score 1):

I really don't recommend using `(Linked)HashMultiSet` to do task which is usually done with `ArrayList` and `(Linked)HashSet` like OP mentioned above - it's less readable for regular Java programmer and (probably) less efficient.

Instead, at least use static factory constructors like [`newArrayList`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v13.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList%28java.lang.Iterable%29) and [`newLinkedHashSet`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v13.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#newLinkedHashSet%28java.lang.Iterable%29) to avoid all these `<T>`s:

```
private static <T> List<T> removeDuplicate(final List<T> list) {
  return Lists.newArrayList(Sets.newLinkedHashSet(list));
}
```

However, you can do it in more "Guava way" - by [avoiding nulls](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained) and using [immutable collections](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained).

So if your collection **cannot** have null elements, I'd suggest using [immutable set](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v13.0.1/javadoc/index.html) instead of [mutable and less efficient one](http://code.google.com/p/memory-measurer/wiki/ElementCostInDataStructures):

```
private static <T> List<T> removeDuplicate(final List<T> list) {
  return Lists.newArrayList(ImmutableSet.copyOf(list));
}
```

It's still copying objects twice, so consider being fully-immutable and changing method signature to return `ImmutableList`:

```
private static <T> ImmutableList<T> removeDuplicate(final List<T> list) {
  return ImmutableSet.copyOf(list).asList();
}
```

This way there is only one copying involved, because [`ImmutableCollection.asList()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v13.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableCollection.html#asList%28%29) returns a view.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Guava's MultiSet API to remove duplicates.Just add your list do the set and use the count method.

[MultiSet](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html)