# Reduce execution time

Tags: java, performance, optimization, hashset

I have a program which simply removes duplicate elements of a character array using HashSet.

Here is my program:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;

import java.util.Set;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        double sT = System.nanoTime();
        Character[] data = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j',
                'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
                'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h',
                'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't',
                'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
                'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r',
                's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
                'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p',
                'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b',
                'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
                'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
                'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
                'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x',
                'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j',
                'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
                'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h',
                'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't',
                'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };

        Set<Character > uniqueSet = new HashSet<Character>(Arrays.asList(data));

         Character[] strArr = new Character[uniqueSet.size()];
         uniqueSet.toArray(strArr);

            for(Character str:strArr){
                System.out.println(str);
            }


        System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - sT);

    }

}
```

It gives the desired output. But problem is execution time. Is there any ways that I can implement in my program to reduce its execution time?

Comment: How is it slow? It looks perfectly reasonable... (except that maybe you want to allocate your char array _before_ the first `.nanoTime()`)

Comment: ..and don't include the printing in your timing...

Comment: @fge yeah it is. But the time it is taking is 1319709.0 nano sec. in average. However, I need it to take no more than 90000 nano sec.

Comment: Timing _one_ execution does not help either. Note that there is the JIT kicking in etc which analyzes your code, etc. Don't time the first execution!

Comment: Your code seems fine to me. You can go thru data[] array, fill uniqueSet and write results to screen in one combined for loop. But it will save just a minimum time.

Comment: @Nim I excluded printing but it did not make much difference. :(

Comment: 90000 nano secs regardles to the length of `data` array?

Comment: Your algorithm's complexity is actually O(1), and that's good. You parse approximately 200 data items in 1319 us, that's approximately 6.5 us per item. I would really like to know why do you think that is slow.

Comment: Why the conversion back to an array before printing? That appears to be redundant(?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the different types of elements that you can have is really small, you can easily use a simple array instead of a hashset(an approach similar to set or counting sort). If you only care for the non-capital English letters declare an array `boolean met[26];`, if you need to be able to support all characters use an `boolean met[256];`.

Than iterate over the array and only add a character to the result if its `met` value is false. When adding the character to the result don't forget to mark it as used.

No hashing involved and thus - better performance.

EDIT: as it seems there is some confusion with what I mean I will try to add a code sample

```
boolean met[] = new boolean[256]; // Replace 256 with the size of alphabet you are using
List<Character> res = new ArrayList<Character>();
for(Character c:data){
  int int_val = (int)c.charValue();
  if (!met[int_val]) {
     met[int_val] = true;
     res.add(c);
  }
}

// res holds the answer.
```

Comment: Character needs 16 bits, at least. And there are only 200 items in the input data array. So I bet your approach will be slower than hash set, because you need to go thru those 65536 items when you want to write the output to screen. But if OP asked for 26 English letters only, that would change the things dramatically.

Comment: @AlKepp I am sorry but I don't think I understand your comment. I suggest using an array of size 256 instead of a hashset. Also my approach requires no hashing -simply mark the element with index corresponding to the character as true. What do you mean by 16 bit?

Comment: @AlKepp he uses the boolean array as marker only, and can index the array elements by the char value

Comment: @AlKepp after the edit of your comment - you never go over the array. You only add an element to the result if the corresponding cell in the array is still false. So you only iterate over the input which is inevitable.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I find your answer quite helpful. Could you please explain it a bit more clearly?

Comment: He meant that UNICODE character will require two bytes to be stored

Comment: @archer still a reasonable size for an array I would say.

Comment: depends what will be the input array. if he use UNICODE chars you should extend the size of your array (as you properly said, using the size of his alphabet)

Comment: btw. one more step - print the output in the same loop, no need for a second loop...

Comment: @Nim I am assuming we are creating a method that computes the result, not just printing the result.

Comment: Can you include your timings for this solution? How much does it speed is up?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I am sorry I did not do any timings. Still it seems certain that this solution will perform at least as efficiently as HashSet(in fact I believe it might be a few times faster).

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev The point I was eluding to is that while that portion of the code will be faster, much of the delay ~40% is in printing the results to the console. If you warmup the code and drop the output in the timing, it will be 50x faster. ;)

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to realise is that writing to the console is very expensive.  If you remove

```
System.out.println(str);
```

This will speed up the code dramatically.

The other thing to note is that you code isn't run long enough to warm up the code (it won't be compiled)  You should run the test for about 2 - 10 seconds to see how long it would take with warmed up code.

The time taken

- with printing => 2,498,085 ns
- without printing => 1,509,978 ns
- if you warn up the code first => 43,347 ns
- if you warm up the code and average 10,000 runs => 18,922 ns
- optimise the code further and run one million times ~2secs => 1,287 ns

End to end that is a 2000x fold performance improvement ;)

The final code looks like

```
StringBuilder strArr = null;
long sT = 0;
int runs = 1000000;
for (int i = -40000; i < runs; i++) {
    if (i == 0)
        sT = System.nanoTime();

    String text = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm" +
            "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm" +
            "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm" +
            "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm" +
            "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm" +
            "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm" +
            "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm" +
            "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm" +
            "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
    BitSet bs = new BitSet(256);
    for (int j = 0, len = text.length(); j < len; j++)
        bs.set(text.charAt(j));
    strArr = new StringBuilder();
    for (int j = -1; (j = bs.nextSetBit(j+1)) >= 0; )
        strArr.append((char) j);
}

System.out.printf("Took an average of %,d ns%n", (System.nanoTime() - sT) / runs);

System.out.print(strArr);
```

prints

```
Took an average of 1,287 ns
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Comment: 1.3 nanoseconds can't be right, there's something being compiled out of existence here.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik 1.3 ns would be wrong (about 4 clock cycles).  It is 1287 ns (about 4000 clock cycles). ;)

Comment: Yes, my Caliper benchmark confirms this. BTW I modified your code to use `new String(...)` because I think it is more realistic to pay for string creation every time (OP is probably not doing this on a constant, otherwise runtime would be irrelevant). I also insist on creating the final `char[]`.

Answer (score 2):

Let Google Caliper take care of microbenchmarking:

```
 0% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=Array} 12868.77 ns; σ=523.07 ns @ 10 trials

  us
12.9

vm: java
trial: 0
benchmark: Array
```

12.9 microseconds. Not quite the same as your 1319 microseconds, is it :)

For reference, this is the exact code:

```
import com.google.caliper.Runner;
import com.google.caliper.SimpleBenchmark;

public class Performance extends SimpleBenchmark {
  public int timeArray(int reps) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int rep = 0; rep < reps; rep++) {
      Character[] data = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p',
          'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i',
          'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b',
          'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u',
          'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
          'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g',
          'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
          'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's',
          't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
          'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e',
          'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x',
          'y', 'z' };
      sum += new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(data))
          .toArray(new Character[new HashSet<Character>
                   (Arrays.asList(data)).size()]).length;
    }
    return sum;
  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
    Runner.main(Performance.class, args);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Guava to do it for you. There is a [Stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242083/remove-duplicates-from-list-using-guava) about it.

Comment: While Guava can improve readability, I wouldn't recommend it for performance.