# How to use Guava to check if every element in a collection are equal to each other

Tags: java, collections

Is there a simple way to use `Guava` to check if my `Collection` contains the same elements?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242083/remove-duplicates-from-list-using-guava

Comment: Your 4 best alternatives are listed in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29288616/276052

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need Guava for that. You can simply pass all the objects from the `Collection` into a `Set` and if you result with a `Set` of size `1`, then all the objects from the `Collection` will be considered as equal (because, as per definition, a `Set` cannot contain duplicates). For example:

```
public boolean checkCollectionForEqualObjects(Collection<SomeObject> collection) {
    Set<SomeObject> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (SomeObject object : collection) {
       set.add(object);
    }
    return set.size() == 1;
}
```

Even better, as @blgt suggested, the `HashSet` class [has a constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet(java.util.Collection)) with a `Collection` parameter, so you can just do:

```
public boolean checkCollectionForEqualObjects(Collection<SomeObject> collection) {
    return new HashSet<>(collection).size() == 1;
}
```

Comment: `HashSet` has a constructor can take a `Collection` as an argument, so you don't need to do the iteration yourself

Comment: Thanks, @blgt. I'll add that to the answer.