# Groovy better way to find out if a list contains all equal values

Tags: groovy

I have the following code for checking if the values in a given list are all equal:

```
def myList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
def myList2 = [1, 1, 1, 1]

def list1EqualVals = myList.collect{ it == myList[0] }.inject(true){it, tmp -> it == tmp}
def list2EqualVals = myList2.collect{ it == myList2[0] }.inject(true){it, tmp -> it == tmp}

println "List 1 has equal values: $list1EqualVals"
println "List 2 has equal values: $list2EqualVals"
```

which works and it prints:

```
List 1 has equal values: false
List 2 has equal values: true
```

but is there a better way of doing this? maybe some method I miss? like list.containsAllEqualValues() or similar

Comment: `myList1 == myList2` ?

Comment: No, I am not comparing the lists, but checking if all values of each list is equal to all other values of the same list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java all determine elements are same in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29288568/java-all-determine-elements-are-same-in-a-list)

Comment: @Edu that's what `==` does... It compares the contents

Comment: Or is it that you want a list of true and false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) into [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html):

> *A collection that contains no duplicate elements.*

and check its [`size()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#size()). If a resulting `Set` has only one element it means all the values in the `List` are the same.

```
def myList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
def myList2 = [1, 1, 1, 1]

def list1EqualVals = myList.toSet().size() == 1
def list2EqualVals = myList2.toSet().size() == 1

println "List 1 has equal values: $list1EqualVals"
println "List 2 has equal values: $list2EqualVals"
```

Alternatively, you can also use the native Groovy [`toUnique()`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#toUnique()) method to achieve the same:

```
def myList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
def myList2 = [1, 1, 1, 1]

def list1EqualVals = myList.toUnique().size() == 1
def list2EqualVals = myList2.toUnique().size() == 1

println "List 1 has equal values: $list1EqualVals"
println "List 2 has equal values: $list2EqualVals"
```

Comment: thanks, passing a false to unique(false) avoids modifying the original List.

Comment: unique(false) is the same as toUnique()

Comment: Thx @PaulKing, I didn't know there's `toUnique()` available. I have corrected the answer with your suggestion.